# Как разархивировать архив tar.gz, в котором архив и т.д?

Tags: linux, bash

Есть архив tar.gz, в котором другой архив tar.gz, в этом архиве другой архив tar.gz и так далее. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как распаковать все эти архивы до конечной точки?

Comment: Создайте бесконечный цикл, в цикле проверка наличия файла *.tar.gz, если файл есть, 1. распаковать файл, 2. удалить файл. Ели файла нет(все распаковано), завершить цикл.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682524/recursive-function-in-bash вот тут почитайте. Должно помочь